# Evaluate monthly fraction of yearly data - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as:

| ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2000 | 5 |
| A | 2/1/2000 | 10 |
| A | 3/1/2000 | 20 |
| A | 4/1/2000 | 10 |
| B | 1/1/2000 | 100 |
| B | 2/1/2000 | 200 |
| B | 3/1/2000 | 300 |
| B | 4/1/2000 | 400 |

How do I evaluate the monthly fraction of the total yearly value for each ID as the fourth column?

| ID | Date | Value | Fraction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2000 | 5 | 0.11 |
| A | 2/1/2000 | 10 | 0.22 |
| A | 3/1/2000 | 20 | 0.44 |
| A | 4/1/2000 | 10 | 0.11 |
| B | 1/1/2000 | 100 | 0.11 |
| B | 2/1/2000 | 200 | 0.22 |
| B | 3/1/2000 | 300 | 0.33 |
| B | 4/1/2000 | 400 | 0.44 |

I guess I could use groupby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data is missing another year to be representative, if you do not have just a single year in the DataFrame.

I just added one line for 2001:

```
import pandas as pd

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

print(df)
```

```
  ID       Date  Value
0  A 2000-01-01      5
1  A 2000-02-01     10
2  A 2000-03-01     20
3  A 2000-04-01     10
4  B 2000-01-01    100
5  B 2000-02-01    200
6  B 2000-03-01    300
7  B 2000-04-01    400
8  B 2001-04-01     20
```

If I understood correctly you can do it like this:

```
df['Fraction'] = (df['Value'] / df.groupby(['ID', df['Date'].dt.year])['Value'].transform('sum')).round(2)

print(df)
```

```
  ID       Date  Value  Fraction
0  A 2000-01-01      5      0.11
1  A 2000-02-01     10      0.22
2  A 2000-03-01     20      0.44
3  A 2000-04-01     10      0.22
4  B 2000-01-01    100      0.10
5  B 2000-02-01    200      0.20
6  B 2000-03-01    300      0.30
7  B 2000-04-01    400      0.40
8  B 2001-04-01     20      1.00
```

Comment: yes.correct. I would need a 'year' column as well to correctly evaluate this!

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the `Value` column by the result of a [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) sum, followed by `round(2)` to match your expected output:

```
df['Fraction'] = df['Value'] / df.groupby('ID')['Value'].transform('sum')
df['Fraction'] = df['Fraction'].round(2)

print(df)

  ID      Date  Value  Fraction
0  A  1/1/2000      5      0.11
1  A  2/1/2000     10      0.22
2  A  3/1/2000     20      0.44
3  A  4/1/2000     10      0.22
4  B  1/1/2000    100      0.10
5  B  2/1/2000    200      0.20
6  B  3/1/2000    300      0.30
7  B  4/1/2000    400      0.40
```